# Function that generates dictionary with optional fields

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use a function to generate a dictionary with some variable fields according to the arguments that I give to the function. The idea is to try multiple configurations and obtain different dictionaries.

I have a function already but it looks non pythonic and it looks very hardcoded.

```py
def build_entry(prefix=None,
                field_a=None,
                field_b=None,
                quantity_a=None,
                quantity_b=None,
                ):
    fields = {}
    if prefix is not None:
        fields['prefix'] = prefix
    if field_a is not None:
        fields['field_a'] = field_a
    if field_b is not None:
        fields['field_b'] = field_b
    if quantity_a is not None:
        fields['quantity_a'] = quantity_a
    if quantity_b is not None:
        fields['quantity_b'] = quantity_b

    return fields
```

The idea is to call the function like this:

```
fields = build_entry(*config) 


Input: [26, 0, None, None, 20]
Output: {'prefix': 26, 'field_a': 0, 'quantity_b': 5}

Input: [20, 5, None, None, None] 
Output: {'prefix': 20, 'field_a':5}

Input: [None, None, 0, 5, None]
Output: {'field_b': 0, 'quantity_a':5}
```

Any idea how to make this function better or more pythonic? Or there is any function that already does this?

I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def build_entry(*values):
  keys = ['prefix', 'field_a', 'field_b', 'quantity_a', 'quantity_b']
  return { k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values) if v is not None}
```

And then called the same way:

```
In [1]: build_entry(*[26, 0, None, None, 20])
Out[1]: {'prefix': 26, 'field_a': 0, 'quantity_b': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like this:

```
def build_entry(**kwargs):
  return kwargs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(build_entry(prefix=1, field_a='a'))
```

Outputs:

```
{'prefix': 1, 'field_a': 'a'}
```